# prove the equation $x^4 + y^4 + z^4 =3009$ has no integer solutions.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

prove the equation $x^4 +  y^4 + z^4 =3009$ has no integer solutions.
I tried modulo 3 and find that it is possible that has integer solutions when $x,y,z$ are all congurent to 0 and 3009 is also congruent to 0 (mod3). And don't know where I get it wrong.

Comment: Why would the existence of solutions mod $3$ imply the existence of solutions in the integers?

Answer (score 2):

Modulo $5$, the fourth powers are $0$ and $1$ only.  The sum of three of them is $0,1,2$ or $3$.  But $3009\equiv4\pmod5$.

Comment: I know there must exist a modulo which can prove that has no solution. Could you explain what is wrong with my proof and why modulo 3 cannot be used.

Comment: If there are integer solutions, then there are solutions modulo $3$.  But it doesn't work the other way around.  Example: $x=x+3$ has solutions modulo $3$, but obviously has no integer solutions.